# Is $\frac14 + \frac15 + \cdots + \frac1{14} + \frac1{15}\lt\frac32$?

Tags: calculus, integration

Use some combination of arithmetic, algebra, and/or elementary integral calculus to determine if the sum

$$\frac14 + \frac15 + \cdots + \frac1{14} + \frac1{15}\lt\frac32$$

Comment: The sum is approximately $1.4849$, so there's not much wiggle room and any approximations are going to have to be quite good.

Comment: You can find the lcm of all those numbers, and crunch them all into one fraction. Then it's as easy as a direct comparison.

Comment: @Kaynex Not that easy!  lcm came out to be 360360, good luck calculating the numerators by hand!

Comment: The hint said to use calculus. Can you make $\sum 1/n < \int 1/n dn $ in any way?  For instance,  if n-1 < x $\le $ n then 1/x $le $ 1/n so 1*1/n < $\int_{n-1}^n$ 1/x dx.

Comment: What appears to have happened is this. The OP solved [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1695211) problem, and was inspired by it to compose this more difficult problem, and post it as a question. It seems to me to have been an entirely innocent misunderstanding as to exactly how a SE site functions, and it is even quite praiseworthy in its way. I hope the episode hasn't put them off from further participation in MathSE.

Comment: As the posing of original problems isn't unambiguously prohibited by [this article](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), I've created a new tag, 'original-problem', and added it to the question. Although that's only closing the stable door after the horse has bolted, perhaps (1) the new tag will help to prevent similar misunderstandings in future, or (2) the guidelines will be revised to make it clearer that "challenge problems" like this and [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1695391) (also by the OP) are not welcome. I don't imagine MathSE will be flooded by such things.

Answer (score 4):

We can make use of the serendipitous fact that the product of the three cumbersome primes $7$, $11$ and $13$ is almost exactly $1000$:

$$
\frac17+\frac1{11}+\frac1{13}=\frac{11\cdot13+13\cdot7+7\cdot11}{1001}=\frac{311}{1001}\lt\frac{311}{1000}\;.
$$

The remaining fractions can be combined like this:

$$
\frac14+\frac18=\frac{3}{8}=\frac{375}{1000}\;,
$$

$$
\frac15+\frac1{10}=\frac3{10}=\frac{300}{1000}\;,
$$

\begin{align}
\frac16+\frac19+\frac1{12}+\frac1{14}+\frac1{15}&\lt\frac16+\frac19+\frac1{12}+\frac1{12}+\frac1{15}\\
&=\frac{30+20+15+15+12}{180}\\
&=\frac{92}{180}\\
&=\frac12+\frac1{90}
\end{align}

The first three sums sum to

$$
\frac{311+375+300}{1000}=\frac{986}{1000}=1-\frac{14}{1000}\;.
$$

Then the desired result follows from

$$
\frac1{90}-\frac{14}{1000}=\frac{100-9\cdot14}{9000}=-\frac{26}{9000}\;.
$$

I'm afraid I haven't used any algebra or calculus, but it does say "and/or". :-)

Comment: Yes, it's an "and/or."

Answer (score 1):

As $\frac1x$ is convex, we get
$$\frac1k \le \int_{k-\frac12}^{k+\frac12}\frac1x dx \quad \implies \sum_{k=4}^{15}\frac1k \le \int_{3.5}^{15.5}\frac1xdx = \log\frac{31}7 < \frac32$$

Of course that still needs you to approximate $\log \frac{13}7$, though on the positive side it would work well for much larger number of terms...

Comment: (You mean you still have to approximate log (31/7).)  Macavity, that is essentially the way I did it with the same value you have, but I posted my problems in the wrong section of this site.  I was supposed to post them in a puzzle section.

Comment: @OliveStemforn: I don't know, it seems a good fit here, too. I think people closed it not so much because it belongs on the puzzle site but because you didn't provide any context or attempts of your own at solving it.

Comment: From the comments on [another problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1695391) posted by the OP, it appears to be a problem she has composed, **not** one she is asking for help with. That was far from clear! Although the OP should have informed herself about SE, her faux pas does raise the fair question of whether there is a site where it is on-topic to set original problems(something I'd never thought of, because I've never made up any problems). On the approximation itself, one can use the first $6$ terms of the series for $e^x$ to get $e^{3/2} > 4\tfrac{591}{1280} > 4\tfrac{3}{7}$.

Comment: @Macavity - I changed the upper limit of integration to $k+1/2$. Not sure why it was originally written as $k-1/2$.